# Is it bad practice to use index.php instead of index.html?

Tags: php, html, indexing, authentication

I'm not sure why it should be, but index.html feels 'right'. I'm using index.php because if my login fails, I want to return to index.php and show the returned error on in the initial log-in page, like this...

```
<?php
   if(isset($_GET["loginFailed"])) {
      echo ($_GET['reason']);
   }
?>
```

That's trimmed a bit, but the 'reason' will be deciphered by the php and a user-friendly error shown.

The login error is just returned from my 'login.php' with something like..

```
if($row === false) {
    die(header("location:index.php?loginFailed=true&reason=usernamenotfound"));
}
```

This all works fine, but I have to keep the index named as index.php instead of index.html. If I change it to index.html, the php part is just ignored.

Is there anything wrong with my approach? Is it unsafe or anything?

Comment: Nothing wrong with `index.php`

Comment: Tis pretty standard to use index.php when developing with PHP. Though most sites nowadays will url rewrite so you wouldn't need / see the index.php or index.html anyway.

Comment: Cool. I'll look up what url rewrite is, but feel free to tell me here :)   Would be nice if you didn't see the 'index.php' in the url I think.

Comment: And there's nothing wrong or unsafe about the url returning from login.php with something like .... http etc... / index.php?loginFailed=true&reason=usernamenotfound ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No issue with using `index.php` instead of `index.html`. It does not affect search engine rankings - So the only reason you would want to change it is for aesthetics.

If you want to use `index.html` instead of `index.php`, there are two options:

Firstly, you can rewrite extensions using .htaccess. Add the following lines to your .htaccess, and they will remap all requests for a .html page to a .php one without the URL changing.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [nc]
```

Secondly, you can allow .html files to be parsed by the PHP interpreter. To do this, add **one** of the following lines to your .htaccess (Different hosts have different syntax, the first works for most shared hosts)

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm

AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

Comment: Thanks, may as well just use index.php then as it's much simpler. The url looks a bit messy when it returns with an error, but that's true of index.html too, e.g it returns with something like index.php?loginFailed=true&reason=usernamenotfound . But if it's not a problem, it's not a problem :)

Comment: @Farflame you can use session() and the url will look "nice". Basically you set a variable that is valid even if the user change page, or go back to index.php

Comment: Ah yeah, session(), I did use that before for something so shouldn't be too difficult. I'll look into that, thanks :)